# Windows explorer seems to be broken?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I have Windows 10 pro x64. 
16gb ddr4 and an i7 5820k.

For the past week or 2 I havent been able to open my start menu, my volume control or the the notification center. But if I push `windows key + e`, the file explorer opens, I can change my volume with my keyboard button, I can right click on the volume button and open volume mixer to change all volumes, which is all part of windows explorer. So I dont understand whats wrong.

I've tried rebooting, I've tried `sfc /scannow`, and that just says "Found issues unable to repair them" So I googled that and found a command to paste the errors to a text document. Idk how to format so [here's the error](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/611caba0f3d9a6d1123b3195988df97f).

The only issue listed is avast so I didnt think anything of it. Then another page I searched said "Avast and CCleaner may cause this issue." I had both installed, so I uninstalled both and rebooted. Still won't open.

Another page said any Overclock might screw it up so I reset my bios and got rid of all my overclock stuff even though I doubt thats the issue because it's still broken, and I've been overclocked for 3 months and had no issues until the past week or so.

Another page said booting into safemode will fix it. It didn't. I ran sfc scannow in safemode too and still got the error.

I have all the latest updates.

My account is an administrator.

Just found another issue. I use gyazo to take screenshots. The keyboard shortcut for that is `ctrl+shift+c` but now that doesnt work anymore either when it used to work fine.

Comment: Windows 10 Start menu is still buggy. Give the [Start menu troubleshooter](http://aka.ms/diag_StartMenu) a shot.

Comment: It said it found an issue but was unable to fix. https://i.gyazo.com/735f3cbd2495f1e08e2860d3018a47b3.png

Comment: create a crash dump: http://pastebin.com/zKuJvw57 and share the compressed dmp file.

Comment: have you captured the crash dump? Otherwise I can't see what is wrong

Comment: @magicandre1981 "C:\Localdumps cannot be found" How do I get the dmp file?

Comment: have you importet the .reg file? are the changes added to the registry? Is the Windows Error reporting service running?

Comment: Tried again. Now it showed up. Do you mind if I upload it to mediafire? I dont have onedrive or dropbox

Comment: mediafire is also ok. Please no hoster which free dl speed of a few kb/s. also notify me via @ my username so that I see you have replied to me

Answer (score 0):

See if reinstalling ShellExperienceHost helps.

[From Start menu and Taskbar Stuck in Windows 10. How to Fix it?](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/start-and-taskbar-stuck-windows-10-fix-shellexperiencehost/)

Open this folder:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
```

Right-click `PowerShell.exe` and click `Run as administrator`.

Paste the following command in the PowerShell window and hit ENTER:

```
Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```

And then execute this:

```
Get-AppxPackage *cortana* | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```

Restart Windows and see if that fixes the problem. If not, re-run the troubleshooter.

Comment: Just tried it. Still wont work. When I click on my volume or start menu, it shows a loading icon for a brief second then stops as if its trying to open it but it cant. Is there anything in event viewer that will tell me whats not letting it open?

Comment: What does the troubleshooter say, now?

Comment: Same exact thing

Comment: There is another variation of the command that reinstalls all packages, but it can be a hit or miss, or in some cases can break other store Apps. I'd wait for 3 more days, and see what the anniversary update (release on Aug 2) has to offer.